# No signing certificate “iOS Development” found - building app release with bitrise/Fastlane match

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, fastlane, bitrise

I’ve inherited a React Native project in my work that builds and deploys app releases to the app store using bitrise and manages all the certificates and code signing using Fastlane match.

I’ve suddenly started getting the following issue on the step that runs this command - `xcodebuild "-exportArchive" "-archivePath" ...`

```
Resolving CodeSignGroups...
Resolving CodeSignGroups...
Filtering CodeSignInfo groups for target capabilities
Filtering CodeSignInfo groups for export method
App was signed with NON Xcode managed profile when archiving,
only NOT Xcode managed profiles are allowed to sign when exporting the archive.
Removing Xcode managed CodeSignInfo groups
Failed to find Codesign Groups
generated export options content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>development</string>
    </dict>
</plist> <nil>
[14:29:56] set -o pipefail && xcodebuild "-exportArchive" "-archivePath" "/var/folders/g2/xnd8hpjs50v433gfrybz2nxh0000gn/T/xcodeArchive091761673/Beryl.xcarchive" "-exportPath" "/var/folders/g2/xnd8hpjs50v433gfrybz2nxh0000gn/T/xcodeIPAExport525207508/exported" "-exportOptionsPlist" "/var/folders/g2/xnd8hpjs50v433gfrybz2nxh0000gn/T/xcodeIPAExport525207508/export_options.plist" | xcpretty
❌  error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found
❌  error: exportArchive: "Beryl.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, Near Field Communication Tag Reading, Sign in with Apple, and Push Notifications features.
❌  Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""xxx.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, Near Field Communication Tag Reading, Sign in with Apple, and Push Notifications features." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="Beryl.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, Near Field Communication Tag Reading, Sign in with Apple, and Push Notifications features., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
❌  error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found
❌  error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found
```

I'm not too sure why this is erroring as everything was working completely fine before. Could anyone suggest how I can debug this or what the issue may be related to here? Any advice would be great, i'm quite new to all of this

Comment: Have you perhaps changed the signing from automatic to manual?

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error. Nothing was changed on our end, the builds just started failing.

Comment: @Kansway I figured out the issue in the end. Turns out there was an update with a breaking change to the Bitrise step, you can read here - https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-archive/releases/tag/4.0.0

This is the one that was breaking it for me - 

`Removed auto-detect option of the distribution_method input. This option has been marked as deprecated for a while. The new default value is development, make sure you select the desired distribution method`

Comment: Yes! This is correct, as selecting an earlier version fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the issue to this in the end.

Turns out there was an update with a breaking change to the Bitrise step, you can read here - https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-archive/releases/tag/4.0.0 This is the one that was breaking it for me

> Removed auto-detect option of the distribution_method input. This option has been marked as deprecated for a while. The new default value is development, make sure you select the desired distribution method

Comment: Where do you find this step?  Having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Inside Xcode Archive & Export for iOS step. You will need to select enterprise if the build type is enterprise and app-store if the build type is the app store. below is the screenshot for reference.

[image: Xcode Archive & Export for iOS step]